# Can two legal complaints be combined in one lawsuit? How does that work?

Tags: british-columbia, legal-research, ohio, civil-legal-system

Our craftswomens cooperative would sue under Chapter 2741 of the Ohio Revised Code (ORC)

prohibiting use of an individual's "persona" for "commercial purposes" without written permission.

Also, we would like to sue for 'libel' resulting in the blacklisting of our jewelry-making group.

Should these two complaints be combined into one? Or are there necessarily two separate cases?

Comment: This site cannot give legal advice. While we may be able to answer questions, you should probably consult a legal professional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### All causes of action from the same circumstances *must* be pursued together

Assuming the statutory infringement and the libel arise from the same acts of the defendant, they must *both* be claimed in the same case (as does any other grievance the plaintiff has) or they cannot be pursued at all.